# How to determine whether the URL is containing argument(s)?

Tags: php, url, routes

I have two kind of URLs:

**First:**

```
localhost/search?q=arg1&s=arg2
```

**Second:**

```
localhost/search/arg1/arg2
```

---

**Note:** Sometimes arguments are containing `?`. Like this:

```
localhost/search/ar?g1/arg2   // this is belong to second kind
```

---

Well, How can I detect ths URL is which kind?

Here is my code:

```
$FirstKind = strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?') ? true : false;
```

But the above code returns `true` for the URL if one of arguments be containing `?` *(as you see in the Note above)*.

Comment: This is bad. According to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2 question-mark is a reserved character

Comment: Please note that `localhost/search/ar?g1/arg2` is NOT a valid url (better: is valid, but `?g1/arg2` is the query)

Comment: To be clear: If you type `localhost/search/ar?g1/arg2` in browser address bar, you'll be redirected to `localhost/search/ar`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parse_url` for this:

```
$parsed = parse_url ( 'YourURL' );
```

The GET ‘arguments’ are now in `$parsed['query']`

---

- See more about [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible implementation:

```
<?php

function getArg($arg, $url) {
    $result = '';
    $urlData = explode('&', parse_url($url)['query']);
    foreach ($urlData as $urlPair) {
        if (strpos($urlPair, '=') !== false) {
            list($k, $v) = explode('=', $urlPair);
            if (trim($k) == $arg) {
                $result = trim($v);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (empty($result)) {
        $urlParts = explode('/', $url);
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($urlParts); $i++) {
            if (trim($urlParts[$i]) == trim($arg)) {
                if (isset($urlParts[$i+1])) {
                    $result = $urlParts[$i+1];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Usage:

```
$url1 = 'localhost/search?q=arg1&s=arg2';
$url2 = 'localhost/search/ar?g1/arg2';

echo "<pre>";

var_dump(getArg('q', $url1));

var_dump(getArg('ar?g1', $url2));

echo "<pre>";
```

Outputs:

```
string(4) "arg1"
string(4) "arg2"
```